# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver when connecting to db from databricks

Tags: java, python, databricks

I am getting the below error when trying to connect to db from databricks using Python:

> Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Code:

```
jdbcHostname = "hostname"
jdbcDatabase = "dbname"
jdbcUsername="user"
jdbcPassword="pwd"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}/{1}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "pwd" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}

pushdown_query = "select top 10 [unique id] from table"
dfcontest= spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(dfcontest)
```

What is wrong here? can you kindly help. 
should we add any jar?

Comment: https://medium.com/@wesmelton/how-to-use-jdbc-mysql-sql-drivers-with-databricks-apache-spark-774544aa856

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should just [pick default driver](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#sql-databases-using-jdbc) `org.mariadb.jdbc` for mysql. Works for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
"driver" : "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```